# Matplotlib : display array values with imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to create a grid using a `matplotlib` function like `imshow`.
From this array:

```
[[ 1  8 13 29 17 26 10  4],
[16 25 31  5 21 30 19 15]]
```

I would like to plot the value as a color AND the text value itself (1,2, ...) on the same grid. This is what I have for the moment (I can only plot the color associated to each value):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

grid = np.array([[1,8,13,29,17,26,10,4],[16,25,31,5,21,30,19,15]])
print 'Here is the array'
print grid

fig1, (ax1, ax2)= pyplot.subplots(2, sharex = True, sharey = False)
ax1.imshow(grid, interpolation ='none', aspect = 'auto')
ax2.imshow(grid, interpolation ='bicubic', aspect = 'auto')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Seaborn heatmap offers this functionality out of the box: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If for any reason you have to use a **different extent** from the one that is provided naturally by `imshow` the following method (even if more contrived) does the job:

[image]

```
size = 4
data = np.arange(size * size).reshape((size, size))

# Limits for the extent
x_start = 3.0
x_end = 9.0
y_start = 6.0
y_end = 12.0

extent = [x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end]

# The normal figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='lower', interpolation='None', cmap='viridis')

# Add the text
jump_x = (x_end - x_start) / (2.0 * size)
jump_y = (y_end - y_start) / (2.0 * size)
x_positions = np.linspace(start=x_start, stop=x_end, num=size, endpoint=False)
y_positions = np.linspace(start=y_start, stop=y_end, num=size, endpoint=False)

for y_index, y in enumerate(y_positions):
    for x_index, x in enumerate(x_positions):
        label = data[y_index, x_index]
        text_x = x + jump_x
        text_y = y + jump_y
        ax.text(text_x, text_y, label, color='black', ha='center', va='center')

fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

If you want to put **other type of data** and not necessarily the values that you used for the image you can modify the script above in the following way (added values after data):

[image]

```
size = 4
data = np.arange(size * size).reshape((size, size))
values = np.random.rand(size, size)

# Limits for the extent
x_start = 3.0
x_end = 9.0
y_start = 6.0
y_end = 12.0

extent = [x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end]

# The normal figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='lower', interpolation='None', cmap='viridis')

# Add the text
jump_x = (x_end - x_start) / (2.0 * size)
jump_y = (y_end - y_start) / (2.0 * size)
x_positions = np.linspace(start=x_start, stop=x_end, num=size, endpoint=False)
y_positions = np.linspace(start=y_start, stop=y_end, num=size, endpoint=False)

for y_index, y in enumerate(y_positions):
    for x_index, x in enumerate(x_positions):
        label = values[y_index, x_index]
        text_x = x + jump_x
        text_y = y + jump_y
        ax.text(text_x, text_y, label, color='black', ha='center', va='center')

fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 54):

You want to loop over the values in `grid`, and use `ax.text` to add the label to the plot.

Fortunately, for 2D arrays, `numpy` has [`ndenumerate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html), which makes this quite simple:

```
for (j,i),label in np.ndenumerate(grid):
    ax1.text(i,j,label,ha='center',va='center')
    ax2.text(i,j,label,ha='center',va='center')
```

[image]

Comment: tom; out of curiosity: is such a loop using `ndenumerate` faster than a manual loop?

Comment: no, I don't think so (although it might depend on the size of `grid`). I just like the simplicity of the code, compared to `for j in range(grid.shape[0]):
    for i in range(grid.shape[1]):
        ax.text(i,j,grid[j,i])`

Comment: Can I do this with a blue text?

Comment: @Daniel, did you try `color='b' ` in the `ax.text` lines?

Comment: Yes, it works :) -- Thank you -- Got it with `color='blue'`